# Error when creating a dynamic list from Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a dynamic table from Angular, my idea is to create a function where the user enters the number of rows and columns and from those values, a table is created with the number of rows and columns that the user has defined. The problem is that when I want to insert a cell for each position of ' i ', the labels are printed literally and a table is not created Code:

HTML

```
<div class="container" id="tabla">
    {{table}}
</div>
```

TypeScript

```
export class tableMaker implements OnInit {
  table: string = '';
  amount: number = 10;

  constructor() {
  }

  dynamicTable(amount: number) {
    this.table = `<table>`;

    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      this.table += `
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      `;
    }
    this.table += '</table>';
  }
}
```

Esto es lo que se imprime en pantalla: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/weOO7.png)

I would like to be able to print a table with a cell in each position of ' i '

Comment: You are storing a string in your `table` variable.  When you use string interpolation in the template like `{{ table }}`, it will just print the literal string, it doesn't parse it as html code.  

In angular you generally don't need to generate html code from the component controller.  You generally handle template concerns in the template. 

Try building up an array of data in your component and use `*ngFor` in the template to repeat each `<tr>`, something like this: `<tr *ngFor="let row of data"> Row #{{ row }} </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Use one way flow syntax property binding:

`<div [innerHTML]="table"></div>`

From angular docs: "Angular recognizes the value as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it, which removes the  tag but keeps safe content such as the  element."

Comment: Hi! the problem is that I need to create a table with 20,000 cells, which would make it impossible for me to create 20,000 cells by hand.

Comment: Yes, I understand. You can still generate the table on your `tableMaker` class. Just render the table with the `[innerHTML]` on the divs.
Just as a recommendation, a table that big can cause a lot of performance problems, so it's a good idea to display the data with some sort of pagination.

Comment: Maybe you mean: `<div [innerHTML]="table"></div> `

Comment: Oh yeah, that, sorry. I will edit my answer, thank you!

Comment: @katana you should use some dependency like ngx-datatable if the table is very big